# boost::archive::binary_iarchive constructor is directly crashing without throwing exception in linux only

Tags: c++, boost, try-catch

We have similar code to the one below:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp"
#include "boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp"

using namespace std;

class MetaData
{
public:
    int old_GroupID;
    int new_GroupID;
    double newpos;
    string newmessg;

    template <typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar& old_GroupID;
        ar& new_GroupID;
        ar& newpos;
        ar& newmessg;
    }

};

void Serialization(const MetaData &object, ofstream &fileStream)
{
    try
    {
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oarch(fileStream);
        oarch & object;
    }
    catch (boost::archive::archive_exception e)
    {

        cout << "boost::archive::archive_exception:exception while serialisation" << e.what() << endl;

    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cout << "unknow exception caught in Serialization" << endl;
    }

}

void DeSerialization(const MetaData &object, stringstream &stringStreamer)
{
    try
    {
        // This crashes instead of throwing
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive iarch(stringStreamer);
        iarch & object;
    }
    catch (boost::archive::archive_exception e)
    {
        cout << "boost::archive::archive_exception: exception" << e.what() << endl;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cout << "unknown exception caught" << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{

    string tempfilename = "/storage/serilazationfile.tmp";

    {

        ofstream OutputStream;
        OutputStream.open(tempfilename, ios::out | ios::binary); //assuming file is opened

        MetaData metadataobjectone;
        metadataobjectone.old_GroupID = 1;
        metadataobjectone.new_GroupID = 5;
        metadataobjectone.newpos = 600.156;
        metadataobjectone.newmessg = "A newmessage for object one";

        Serialization(metadataobjectone, ofstream);

        MetaData metadataobjecttwo;
        metadataobjecttwo.old_GroupID = 2;
        metadataobjecttwo.new_GroupID = 6;
        metadataobjecttwo.newpos = 800.192;
        metadataobjecttwo.newmessg = "A newmessage for object two";

        Serialization(metadataobjecttwo, ofstream); //this seralize object , in the file should be corrupted like adding spaces or add unwanted data. 

        OutputStream.flush();
        OutputStream.close();

    }

    stringstream stringStreamer;
    ifstream InputStream;
    InputStream.open(tempfilename, ios::in | ios::binary);
    stringStreamer << InputStream.rdbuf();
    stringStreamer.seekg(0, stringStreamer.end);
    size_t FileSize = stringStreamer.tellg();
    stringStreamer.seekg(0, stringStreamer.beg);

    while (true)
    {
        MetaData object;//MetaData is a userdefined structure
        DeSerialization(object, stringStreamer); //while deserializing 2nd oject(corrupted) exe will be crash in linux but it will not crash in windows.
        //doing something with deserialized data
        if (FileSize == stringStreamer.tellg())
        {
            break;
        }
    }


}
```

We are deliberately corrupting `serilazationfile.tmp` (by adding newlines or unwanted data) to handle negative cases like when a file is corrupted by a chance or a file has invalid data in live environment.

In Windows, when deserializing that corrupted file, some exception is thrown and caught "unknown exception", but in Linux it is straightaway crashing, i.e. in Linux it is uncatchable.

**So what is the issue in here, why is the condition uncatchable in Linux?**

Tested with Boost version 1_58, x64bit ubuntu 18.05 and x64bit Windows server 2016.

We got the below callstack:-

```
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00007f36efef7921 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007f36edd53b21 in Vmacore::PanicExit(char const*) () from /usr/lib/vmware/libvmacore.so
#3  0x00007f36edb1a75d in ?? () from /usr/lib/vmware/libvmacore.so
#4  0x00007f36f08f12ac in operator new(unsigned long) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007f36f0931c29 in std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007f36f0932afb in std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned long) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x00007f36f0932bb4 in std::string::reserve(unsigned long) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#8  0x00007f36f0932f9c in std::string::append(unsigned long, char) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#9  0x0000000002d97876 in boost::archive::basic_binary_iprimitive<boost::archive::binary_iarchive, char, std::char_traits<char> >::load(std::string&) ()
#10 0x0000000002d97a35 in boost::archive::basic_binary_iarchive<boost::archive::binary_iarchive>::init() ()
#11 0x00000000017a4ea3 in boost::archive::binary_iarchive_impl<boost::archive::binary_iarchive, char, std::char_traits<char> >::init (this=0x7f365d139570, flags=0)
    at /usr/local/include/boost/archive/binary_iarchive_impl.hpp:68
#12 0x00000000017a4182 in boost::archive::binary_iarchive_impl<boost::archive::binary_iarchive, char, std::char_traits<char> >::binary_iarchive_impl (
    this=0x7f365d139570, is=..., flags=0) at /usr/local/include/boost/archive/binary_iarchive_impl.hpp:97
#13 0x00000000017a3c93 in boost::archive::binary_iarchive::binary_iarchive (this=0x7f365d139570, is=..., flags=0)
    at /usr/local/include/boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp:44
**#14 0x0000000002697c4a in CustmSerialization::Deserialization<MetaData*, std::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > (
    this=0x7f365d13a0dc, object=@0x7f365d1398b0: 0xd68, fileStream=...)
```

In `CustmSerialization::Deserialization` here we have deserialization logic similar to the above example, and we have `catch(...)` in place, but the exception is not getting caught.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @DevSolar i have provide the necessary details, can you check now .

Comment: That example still had a long way to go. The idea is that anyone could just copy your example, paste, compile, and see exactly what you are talking about in your question. I added the necessary includes, `main()`, and some proper indentation. I also fixed FileSize missing a type. The code still doesn't compile, as `someobjecttype` is not declared, and I am not at all sure if `iarch & object;` is the correct syntax, but then again I have not worked with Boost.Serialization myself. Just trying to show you how to write up a question that stands a chance of being answered. ;-) Close vote retracted

Comment: Having a short, *specific* input example would also help. -- Note that you can `catch( const std::exception &e ) { std::cerr << e.what(); }`, or `catch( ... ) { boost::current_exception_diagnostic_information(); }` when you `#include "boost/exception/diagnostic_information.hpp"`.

Answer (score 1):

Without self-contained reproducer, we can only guess.

Firstly, let me write a demonstration that doesn't have the problem. Then I'll **guess** in which way your (hidden) implementation invokes [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

### Working Demo

Let's make a `save` and `load` function that print some debug output on the way:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7cc9342b4a99cdf)**

```
#include "boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp"
#include "boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

struct MetaData {
    int i;
    void serialize(auto& ar, unsigned) { ar& i; }
};

void save(std::vector<MetaData> data, std::string const& filename)
{
    std::ofstream ofs(filename, std::ios::binary);

    for (auto& object : data) {

        try {
            boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);
            oa << object;
        } catch (std::exception const& e) {
            std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        } catch (...) {
            std::cerr << "unknown exception caught" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cerr << "save tellp: " << ofs.tellp() << "\n";
    }
}

auto load(std::string const& filename)
{
    std::stringstream mem;
    {
        std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ios::binary);
        mem << ifs.rdbuf();
    }

    mem.seekg(0, mem.end);
    auto const FileSize = mem.tellg();

    mem.seekg(0, mem.beg);

    std::vector<MetaData> data;
    do {
        std::cerr << "load tellg: " << mem.tellg() << ", FileSize:" << FileSize << "\n";
        auto& object = data.emplace_back();

        try {
            // This crashes instead of throwing
            boost::archive::binary_iarchive iarch(mem);
            iarch >> object;
        } catch (std::exception const& e) {
            std::cerr << "boost::archive::archive_exception: exception" << std::endl;
        } catch (...) {
            std::cerr << "unknown exception caught" << std::endl;
        }

        // doing something with deserialized data
    } while (mem.tellg() < FileSize);

    return data;
}

int main()
{
    save({{11}, {22}, {33}}, "test.bin");

    std::cout << "----\n";
    for (auto& obj : load("test.bin")) {
        std::cout << "object " << obj.i << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints, e.g.:

```
save tellp: 49
save tellp: 98
save tellp: 147
----
load tellg: 0, FileSize:147
load tellg: 49, FileSize:147
load tellg: 98, FileSize:147
object 11
object 22
object 33
```

### Enter Crystal Ball

I can imagine that you didn't complete the archives when required:

```
void save(std::vector<MetaData> data, std::string const& filename)
{
    std::ofstream ofs(filename, std::ios::binary);

    try {
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);
        for (auto& object : data) {
            oa << object;
            std::cerr << "save tellp: " << ofs.tellp() << "\n";
        }
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    } catch (...) {
        std::cerr << "unknown exception caught" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Trying to read this using that same load function results in:

```
load tellg: 0, FileSize:57
load tellg: 49, FileSize:57
=================================================================
==31200==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: allocator is out of memory trying to allocate 0x2100000017 bytes
    #0 0x7fbbe371b717 in operator new(unsigned long) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.6+0xb4717)
    #1 0x7fbbde4bc8b9 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_mutate(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6+0x13d8b9)

==31200==HINT: if you don't care about these errors you may set allocator_may_return_null=1
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: out-of-memory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.6+0xb4717) in operator new(unsigned long)
==31200==ABORTING
```

That's remarkably similar to your stack trace.

You can fix it like above, or match the reading function (which is how archives are intended, mostly):

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/738470be43b0d2e5)**

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

struct MetaData {
    int i;
    void serialize(auto& ar, unsigned) { ar& i; }
};

void save(std::vector<MetaData> const& data, std::string const& filename) {
    std::ofstream ofs(filename, std::ios::binary);
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << data;
}

auto load(std::string const& filename) {
    std::vector<MetaData> data;

    std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ios::binary);
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive iarch(ifs);
    iarch >> data;

    return data;
}

int main() {
    save({{11}, {22}, {33}}, "test.bin");

    for (auto& obj : load("test.bin")) {
        std::cout << "object " << obj.i << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
object 11
object 22
object 33
```

Note how this version is a fraction of the code.

Comment: i have edited the question please check now once. In the question i have mentioned second serialized object should be corrupt and while deserialzing 2nd object in linux it will be crashed i.e. uncatchable where as in windows that will work fine i.e. error will get caught in the catch block.

Comment: I'm afraid fuzz testing like that is prone to uncover UB. It's not really surprising that if you put garbage in, it will not be specified what will happen. You should probably make your own archive format that has checksums, and uses limits on deserialization. If you really want to make it secure you need cryptographic methods (HMAC e.g.). All those are not features of the library.

Comment: Actually we are putting that garbage is to reproduce the case in where the serialized data written in disk is corrupted and later when we try to deserialize that data in linux it is crashing while in windows it is not. i wondered,why it is crashing only in linux even though we have handled code with catch(...) block.

Comment: It's just triggering UB. That might be considered a bug (though resilience/security isn't explicitly listed a feature). You can always trace where it goes wrong (apparently it's simply doing runaway allocations with mis-interpreted sizes, nothing magical) and propose hardening patches. But like I said, the only real fix is to have a custom archive implementation that adds e.g. HMAC to the stream so you reliably reject corrupted streams.